Why is 00:00:00:00:00:00 address used instead of broadcast address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff in ARP?
The following is my stripped down ARP ruleset, only broadcast rules are shown, other rules (not shown here) are not relevant.
Please see code comments that are questions (?)
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

add chain arp arp_table input {
    # filter = 0
    # Packets delivered to the local system
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
}

add chain arp arp_table output {
    # filter = 0
    # Packets send by the local system
    type filter hook output priority filter; policy drop;
}

# ARP Broadcast address
define broadcast_ether = { ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff }

# IPv4 network address
define network_addr_4 = { 192.168.1.0/24 }

# NIC ether address
define physical_ether = { bb:c9:51:d4:4a:b6 }

# Why input to broadcast address never hits?
# This rule should handle broadcast input
add rule arp arp_table input arp daddr ether $broadcast_ether log prefix "ACCEPT input broadcast: " accept

# Why input to 00:00:00:00:00:00 hits instead?
# This rule handles input toward 00:00:00:00:00:00 from LAN
add rule arp arp_table input arp saddr ip $network_addr_4 arp daddr ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 accept

# Why output to broadcast never hits?
# This rule should handle output toward ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff to LAN
add rule arp arp_table output arp daddr ether $broadcast_ether log prefix "ACCEPT output broadcast: " accept

# Why output to 00:00:00:00:00:00 hits instead?
# This rule handles output toward 00:00:00:00:00:00 to LAN
add rule arp arp_table output arp saddr ether $physical_ether arp daddr ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 accept

There are several questions here, the main one being that ARP broadcast traffic ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is nonexistent, that's why I added log statement to hopefully catch such traffic but it never appears, for both input and output traffic.
What happens instead is I see a lot of intput/output directed toward 00:00:00:00:00:00 address, which suggests that 00:00:00:00:00:00 is broadcast address somehow.
So the main question is why don't I see ARP traffic directed toward broadcast address and why is 00:00:00:00:00:00 address used instead?
2nd question is, what is 00:00:00:00:00:00 address? why it is needed and what does it mean?
If I block traffic to/from 00:00:00:00:00:00 (ex. by removing those rules) then networking will stop to function due to a such ARP packets being dropped.

arp daddr ether does not refer to the destionation MAC address in the frame header, but Target hardware address (THA) in the ARP packet. For ARP request, this field is "ignored" / "unfilled".

To match the address in the frame header, IIRC the syntax should be ether daddr (with no arp before that; but you can have something like arp saddr ip xxx ether daddr xxx, I think).

Since the beginning of packet networking, the "All Ones" AND the "All Zeros" addresses were both used as "Broadcast Addresses". Initially done to not preclude hardware design choices. "Be conservative with what you send, liberal with what you receive".

@waltinator, perhaps so, but it's not likely that any particular single protocol would use both for broadcast. In Ethernet, the low bit of the first byte marks unicast vs. multicast, making all-zeros a unicast address. And if you're thinking about IP addresses, the all-zeros host address within a network was used for broadcast in some BSD version something like 30+ years ago, and it's since mostly just considered "reserved". Being liberal in what you receive is a bad guideline, since it allows systems to ignore reserved fields/values preventing their use for meaningful future expansion.

The nftables wiki lists ether {saddr | daddr} «ether_addr» for matching the source and destination in the Ethernet header; and arp {saddr | daddr } ether «ether_addr» for matching the Sender Hardware Address (SHA) and Target Hardware Address (THA) in the ARP header. The commands could perhaps be more clearly named, both to make a clearer distinction between the ARP and Ethernet headers, and also because the field in the ARP header is called the target address, not the destination(*).
The Ethernet destination address of an ARP request would be the broadcast address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff since the request by necessity has to be sent to every possible responder.
You probably shouldn't rely on the ARP target hardware address of an ARP request containing anything in particular, as that's the value the sender of the packet doesn't know and is querying for. It's likely to be set to all zeros as you saw, but RFC 826 seems to leave the door open for it being anything:

The Address
Resolution module then sets [...]
ar$op to ares_op$REQUEST, ar$sha with the 48.bit ethernet address
of itself, ar$spa with the protocol address of itself, and ar$tpa
with the protocol address of the machine that is trying to be
accessed.  It does not set ar$tha to anything in particular,
because it is this value that it is trying to determine.  It
could set ar$tha to the broadcast address for the hardware (all
ones in the case of the 10Mbit Ethernet) if that makes it
convenient for some aspect of the implementation.

(* practicalnetworking.net points out a difference in meaning between "target" and "destination" here: in the case of Proxy ARP, the host being queried about (the "target") would not see the query itself (and so would not be its "destination") since some other host answers on its behalf.)

Very well explained and good discovery of nftables wiki! I did read the RFC in it's entirety and noticed that quote but still did not understand what's the use of ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff in relation to ARP.
